# Saving/Updating a Wikifield column for Wiki Library using JSOM

Tags: javascript, jsom, content-editor-web-part

I've written some code in an attempt to keep a Content Editor Web Part in sync with a Wiki Pages Library.

This code executes and states that it's completed successfully without error. Checking the wiki page itself shows no updated content however. What am I doing wrong?

(This is SharePoint 2013 if that matters).

```
updateWiki: function () {
            var tabContent2 = $("#mainTabstrip-2 .ms-rtestate-field").html();
            
            HCE.Page.getItemsWithCaml("FAQwiki").then(
                function (listItemCollection, clientContext) {
                    var listItemEnumerator = listItemCollection.getEnumerator();
                    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

                        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                            //success
                            Function.createDelegate(this,
                                function () {
                                    console.log(oListItem.get_item("PageName"));
                                    if (oListItem.get_item("PageName") == "FAQ") {
                                        oListItem.set_item("WikiField", tabContent2);
                                        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                                            //success
                                            Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
                                                console.log("Wiki content update successful for FAQ.");
                                            }),
                                            //fail
                                            Function.createDelegate(function (sender, e) {
                                                console.log("error updating WikiField content for FAQ: " + e.get_message() + "\n" + e.get_stackTrace());
                                            })
                                        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out I was missing this line:

```
oListItem.update();
```

after:

```
oListItem.set_item("WikiField", tabContent2);
```